# How to run testng maven project jar with profile as an option from command prompt

Tags: maven, testng

I have created a maven project which has got Testng scripts. I have created multiple maven profile in my POM.xml file. I have added the below plugin to create a jar file for my project. But how can I run this jar file passing maven profile as the option (I don't have any main class for my project)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Regards,
Kiran

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve and provide the complete pom file. If you want to run a specific profile use "mvn <phase> -P <profile>"
Do you mean JUnit tests with "Testing scripts"? To run those, create the tests under "src/test/java" and name them *Test, so that the maven-surefire-plugin finds them, when executed in test phase. Run "mvn test" to compile and execute the tests or run one of the phases after test, which are all including the test phase implicitly. The default lifecycle: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference

Comment: I have developed scripts but developers wants to use them but they don't want to install dependencies but only run that jar which should trigger script